# Windows 10 Toast Notifications quits my PyQt app when it's done

Tags: python, pyqt

So my code opens a GUI timer that counts down. Looks like this:

[image]

So according to the code, the app will countdown initially from 15 seconds and when it reaches zero it will reset to 5 seconds, then 15 again. Ultimate goal is to remind me to do something for a few seconds, every few minutes. These initial times are just for the sake of testing.

So when the timer is zero, I'm waiting a few seconds before it resets to the inital int. In the meanwhile, I'm trying to show a window 10 toast notification but the issue is that when it appears, the clock is stuck and after that period the app closes. So basically I can see the toast for a few seconds, but the timer will not reset and the app will close.

Here is my code:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys
import time
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
import itertools

DURATION_INT = 15
toaster = ToastNotifier()
TIME_CYCLER = itertools.cycle([15, 5])  # 10 minutes, 10 seconds

def secs_to_minsec(secs: int):
    mins = secs // 60
    secs = secs % 60
    minsec = f'{mins:02}:{secs:02}'
    return minsec

class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT
        self.myTimer = QtCore.QTimer(self)

        # App window
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.win = QMainWindow()
        self.win.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)
        self.win.setWindowTitle("test")

        # Widgets
        self.titleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.win)
        self.titleLabel.setText("Welcome to my app")
        self.titleLabel.move(50,20)

        self.timerLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.win)
        self.timerLabel.move(50,50)
        self.timerLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.timerLabel.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt Helvetica")

        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.win)
        self.startButton.setText("Start")
        self.startButton.move(50,100)
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.startTimer)

        self.stopButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.win)
        self.stopButton.setText("Minimize")
        self.stopButton.move(50,130)

        self.update_gui()

        # Show window
        self.win.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def startTimer(self):
        self.time_left_int = next(TIME_CYCLER)

        self.myTimer.timeout.connect(self.timerTimeout)
        self.myTimer.start(1000)

    def timerTimeout(self):
        self.time_left_int -= 1
        if self.time_left_int == 0:
            toaster.show_toast("test", "test", duration=5)
            self.time_left_int = next(TIME_CYCLER)


        self.update_gui()

    def update_gui(self):
        minsec = secs_to_minsec(self.time_left_int)
        self.timerLabel.setText(minsec)

    # def minimize():
    #     pass

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = App()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Maybe my logic is flawed with the `def timerTimeout(self):`function, but from my understanding, the timer should reach zero, show the notification, reset `self.time_left_int` to the next value, then call the `self.update_gui()` function. In my case, it seems like the `show_toast` is the last thing to happen.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like after further research, toaster has a `threaded` parameter, so editing this in fixed the issue:

```py
toaster.show_toast("test", "test", duration=5, threaded=True)`
```